No counter 'refsection' defined. \defcounter {refsection}{0}
I'm new to latex, and i've encountered a following problem: if I add natbib package, I get an error:
No counter 'refsection' defined. \defcounter {refsection}{0}

ChatGPD says it's a conflict with hyperref, but it does not provide any meaningful advice on how to fix it.
Here's my preamble:
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[space]{grffile} % allows using paths that contain spaces
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage[]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{sansmathaccent}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}
\usepackage{pifont}

\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%
\pdfmapfile{+sansmathaccent.map}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,      
    urlcolor=black,
}
\makeatletter

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\tikzset{
    highlight on/.style={alt={#1{fill=red!80!black,color=red!80!black}{fill=gray!30!white,color=gray!30!white}}},
}

\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{my_theme}      % or try default, Darmstadt, Warsaw, ...
\usecolortheme{orchid} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...

%\setcitestyle{authoryear}


\AtBeginSection[]{
    \begin{frame}
        \vfill
        \centering
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
            \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
        \end{beamercolorbox}
        \vfill
    \end{frame}
}



\AtBeginSubsection[]{
    \begin{frame}
        \vfill
        \centering
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
            \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
        \end{beamercolorbox}
        \vfill
    \end{frame}
}


\newcommand{\sym}[1]{{#1}}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}  
\bibliography{literature.bib}

I would be grateful for any advice!

you have posted a lot of code but none of it related to your question and it generated ! LaTeX Error: File \beamerthememy_theme.sty' not found.and then ends at the*prompt as there is no\end{document}` please remove all packages unrelated to your question and provide an example that makes the error that you are asking about,

Thank you for your comment! Unfortunately, I'm totally new to latex, and hence I cannot figure out which part of the code is related to the problem. Since a conflict between packages could be a possible cause, I've posted my preamble with the list of all packages used. I've tried to make a reproducible example, but when I reduce the content of the document, the error message changes to something completely different... so I was hoping to get some ideas from the crowd that might come up from the error message alone

No you can always provide an example. Start with a copy of the document and delete everything that you can delete while still showing the problem.  all we know is in some code not shown you have used a counter that is not defined, I suppose the simplest thing to do woult be to define the counter with \newcounter{refsection} but that is highly unlikely to be the fix.  If you delete all the unreleated code you have shown your example is  \documentclass{article}\begin{document}\addtocounter{wibble}{1}\end{document} which gives the error you are asking about.

You could fix it by defining the counter or removing the use of the undefined counter, but as you have shown no code, it is impossible to say which you should do

For more information about what David is asking for → I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that? and because you say, that it is because of loading natbib also: How to write a MWEB (Minimal working example with Bibliography)?
